# Template programming and bit fields

Tags: c++, templates, bit-fields

I need the following two very similar structures in my code:

```
union ArrayEntry2Byte {          union ArrayEntry4Byte {
  struct {                         struct {
    char foo : 1;                    char foo : 1;
    short bar : 15;                   int bar : 31;
  };                               };
  short foobar;                    int foobar;
  // other code                    // other code
};                               };
```

In order to increase maintainability and elegance of this code, I want to remove one of these structures using template programming:

```
template<typename value_type>
union ArrayEntry {
  struct {
    char foo : 1;
    value_type bar : 15;
  };
  value_type foobar;
  // other code
};
```

However, the bit field brings me into trouble. All I need is something like this:

```
value_type bar : (value_type == short ? 15 : 31);
```

But, well, that’s obviously no correct syntax. How can I elegantly solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a C++11 solution:

```
#include <limits>

template <typename value_type>
union ArrayEntry {
    struct {
        char foo : 1;
        value_type bar : std::numeric_limits<value_type>::digits;
    };
    value_type foobar;
    // other code
};
```

Comment: That's nice, however, I think I oversimplified my problem. Imagine we have the following struct inside the union: `struct { char foo : 1; short bar1 : 7; short bar2 : 8 }` or respectively `struct { char foo : 1; int bar1 : 15; int bar2 : 16 }`. Then I have to resort to 0x499602D2's solution, haven't I?

Comment: @user1494080 Yes, in such case you have to prefer 0x499602D2's solution if these magic numbers can't be taken from the number of bits of `value_type` type using some formula.

Comment: Actually they can. :) I was at a loss, your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Create a private template that returns the correct value:

```
template<typename T>
struct bitFieldValue : std::integral_constant<int, 31>
{ };

template<>
struct bitFieldValue<short> : std::integral_constant<int, 15>
{ };
```

Then later on:

```
value_type bar : bitFieldValue<value_type>::value;
```

Comment: Why create a trait when you could use `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits`?

Comment: @rici Did not realize that. Good one. +1 to the other answer.

Comment: That's probably a beginner's question, but what are _private_ templates?

Comment: @user1494080 By *private template* I meant just create them under the `private:` label in your union. Similar to a private data member of a class.